# How is it possible that position absolute top 0px and right 0px are not working?

Tags: html, css

The element with "go forward" is supposed to be at the top-right corner; why is it not at that spot when the pertaining style contains "`position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px;`" ?

Here is a link to the page

link removed

Comment: please post a jsfiddle and/or the code so that future visitors will be able to see the whole question

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your rule:

```
#slidecarousel div {
    position: relative;
    top: 5%;
}
```

is overriding the other rule. It's related to the rule's specificity. You could change the `#sliderButtonF` selectors of your rule to be:

```
#slidecarousel #sliderButtonF {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

which should do the trick.

Comment: thanks for the tip. It was gratefully taken...

Comment: @DaMaxContent : accept the answer if it worked for u!! :)